# Exception while running liquibase diff in spring framework 6

Tags: java, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

Creating a new project in spring boot 3 using JDK 17. maven liquibase:diff - giving following errors :

Caused by[m: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: [1;31m'javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo()'[m
[1mat[m liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringPackageDatabase.createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder ([1mHibernateSpringPackageDatabase.java:86[m)
[1mat[m liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateEjb3Database.buildMetadataFromPath ([1mHibernateEjb3Database.java:57[m)

Below is my pom.xml file:

```
<profile>
        <id>liquibase</id>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.4.1</version>

                    <configuration>
                        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                        <logging>info</logging>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>update-profile</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>diff-profile</id>
                            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>diff</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                            <version>8.0.26</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                            <version>4.19.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                            <version>6.0.6</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                            <version>6.0.6</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                            <version>6.0.6</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.3</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                            <version>3.29.0-GA</version>
                        </dependency>
                        
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                        
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>


        </build>
    </profile>
```

Added different dependencies under liquibase plugin.
Isn't in JDK17 : javax.persistence is replaced by jakarata.persistence

Comment: Try using the latest version of `liquibase-maven-plugin`

Comment: Tried with latest 4.20.0 version, it also gives the same exception

Comment: You have `liquibase-hibernate5` in your dependency, but spring framework 6 requires hibernate 6 use `liquibase-hibernate6` for hibernate 6.